# Changing an element's CSS with respect to different languages

Tags: javascript, css, font-size, typography

Is there a way to use CSS to style text depending on the language?

For example the font *Tahoma* is widely used for Arabic text, but its size is very tiny when it comes to English text with the same text size.

So, when we have some English text within an Arabic text, is there a way to automatically detect the change in text language and then use a bigger font size for the English text that is withing the Arabic one.

Thanks.

Comment: it would be more appropriate to add javascript tag..

Comment: In what context? Writting something on an input or displaying contents from the server?

Comment: thanks for both answers but I really didn't get the point :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a mechanism to do this, but you could try your luck by iterating over every text node in JavaScript and testing for characters A-Z insensitively (`match(/^[a-z]+$/i)` (though this doesn't guarantee the text will be *English*).

If true, you could attach a class to the parent element, something like `appears-english` and then have CSS like `.appears-english { font-size: 120% }`.

#### Update

As per request, here is some code...

#### JavaScript

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0, divsLength = divs.length; i < divsLength; i++) {
  var div = divs[i];

    if (div.firstChild.nodeValue.match(/^[a-z]+$/)) {
       div.className += 'appears-english';
    }  

}
```

#### CSS

```
.appears-english {
   font-size: 170%;  
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RrQDq/).

You can see from the fiddle it doesn't match if there are numbers - you can make it match numbers, letters and underscore by [changing `[a-z]` in the regex to `\w`](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RrQDq/1/).

BTW, if you want to update English characters within an element that also contains Arabic characters, you will need to use `replace()` and wrap them with `span` elements, of which you then add `appears-english` to.

Comment: thanks for the answer alex. It's not a must to be english, but just using english letters. I think this could get the job done, but would you give me an example code? thanks.

Comment: @MohamedKadri Sure can, any libraries present, such as jQuery?

Comment: yes, jQuery is what I use, but if no problem I want it raw javascript so that it doesn't flash at first when the jQuery isn't yet loaded.

Comment: ok thanks alex, I will try the code, but now I have to sleep, it's 03:48 am ;)

Comment: @MohamedKadri That's the best time to start coding :)

Comment: Yes I know, but I must go the morning to pay for my ADSL and I have some other things to do, but I really want to stay as no one disturbs me now. Another question please, how does this work? does it re-style every single character alone or it takes all the characters and put them in a div to style them on the fly?

Comment: @MohamedKadri It attaches a class to the element of whom its text node is all `a-z`. CSS then picks this up and increases the `font-size` (using a percentage so hopefully maintenance is easier).

Comment: @MohamedKadri Thanks. People always like my useless plugin. Funny world isn't it? :P

Comment: @MohamedKadri Awesome, shoot me an email once done, I always like to see my plugins in action.